# SOAP Request fails with Xcode 8 in iOS 10

Tags: ios, soap, ios10, xcode8

I'm working on iOS App which loads data using SOAP Requests.
All things are working properly in iOS 9 or earlier. I have updated xcode and running app and getting below error while fetching data using simple "GET" method.

ERROR:
The ERROR : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xyz.com.au/webservice/xyz.php, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xyz.com.au/webservice/xyz.php, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x14d7dff0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x10020050325790c40000000000000000}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xyz.com.au/webservice/xyz.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xyz.com.au/webservice/xyz.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}}}

I'm using NSURLConnection standard code for calling WS.

Please help in critical issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following solution.**

1) Restarting the simulator fixed the issue for me.

2) For mine, Resetting content and settings of Simulator works.

3) Increase `KeepAliveTimeout` time for request.

4) Make sure about your request parameter.

Comment: I'm using device.

Answer (score 0):

Use *NSURLSession* instead of *NSURLConnection*.

Answer (score 0):

Same error here with some parameters sent by POST method, and pdf file as response. Same code was perfectly running on iOS<10

No solution found yet but for me the problem occurs only when the request is sent through a VPN or a proxy server. Is it the same for you?

Answer (score 0):

to Shiner
I have same trouble. In browsers on Ipad (ios 10). Ipad connected over VPN. If try open any page with long response time( > 2 min), then connection losted. In console "Failed to load resorce: The request timed out"